# Hibernate omits tenantId clause on some queries

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, multi-tenant

I'm using Hibernate v6.4.1.Final and Postgres 15 with the `@TenantId` annotation on my Hibernate Entities.

The Hibernate [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy-hibernate-TenantId) say this means that entities will always be filtered based on the current tenantId from `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`. I thought this was working well for me, but I recently noticed that for *some* entities, the `where tenant_id = ?` clause is not included!

The queries missing the `WHERE tenant_id = ?` clause use the same repository method: `SimpleJpaRepository.findById`. Their `tenant_id` column is setup in exactly the same way:

```
  @Column(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long tenantId;
```

For example the query from `CExpenseRepository.findById`:

```
public interface CExpenseRepository
    extends JpaRepository<CExpenseBE, Long>,
        PagingAndSortingRepository<CExpenseBE, Long> {}
```

> INFO [tenantId:1] --- n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener Query:["select ceb1_0.id,ceb1_0.amount,set1_0.id,set1_0,set1_0.tenant_id,ceb1_0.tenant_id from c_expense ceb1_0 join s_expense_type set1_0 on set1_0.id=ceb1_0.s_expense_type_id where ceb1_0.id=?"], Params:[(4)]

A different type of entity that is set up exactly the same does produce the `tenant_id` clause:

> INFO [tenantId:1] --- n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener ]Query:["select sd1_0.id,sd1_0.address1 from sales_order sob1_0 join shipping_destination sd1_0 on sd1_0.id=sob1_0.shipping_destination_id where sob1_0.tenant_id = ? and sob1_0.id=?"], Params:[(1,2)]